# Extend kebab-case regex to also allow double underscore separator

Tags: javascript, regex

The default regex used by Stylelint to check CSS class names is

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

This allows kebab-cased names such as `foo-bar`. I want to change this to also allow a double-underscore to be used as a separator within the name, e.g. all of the following should be considered valid

- `foo-bar`
- `v-list-item__prepend`
- `v-list-item__spacer`

In other words, a double-underscore separator is *allowed* but not *required*. I expected the following to work, but it doesn't

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(__)?(-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Maybe `^([a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:__[a-z0-9]+)*)(-[a-z0-9]+(?:__[a-z0-9]+)*)*$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that it only allows for a single optional double-underscore after the initial word. After that, only the kebab-case pattern is allowed.

This could work: `^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(__[a-z0-9]+|-{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regex to allow BEM type classnames:

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*(__[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^`** - start of line
- **`([a-z][a-z0-9]*)`** - First capturing group matching lowercase letters and digits 0 or more times.
- **`(-[a-z0-9]+)*`**  - Second capturing group matching atleast 1 letter or digit followed by a `-`. This group can also exist 0 or more time.
- **`(__[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)?`** - Third and 4th capturing group (the required one) which supports `__` followed by atleast 1 letter or digit which in turn is followed by the defintion of second capturing group and this group also exists 0 or 1 times.
- **`$`** - End of line.

[image]

***[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Pz35kR/1)***

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `-` with `(-|__)`

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)((-|__)[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

This will however allow `v-list-item__prepend-foo`